# SQL finding max value of column where another column has got maximum but repetable value

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have following table:

```
id  year    month
1   2019    9
2   2019    10
3   2019    11
4   2019    12
5   2020    1
6   2020    2
7   2020    3
8   2020    4
```

I need to select max value of column month but only from where year has got max value.
In that case i need to select row

```
id  max_year    max_month
8   2020        4
```

I tried to make it with this

```
SELECT m.id, m.max_year, MAX(m.month) AS max_month FROM (SELECT id, month, MAX(year) AS max_year FROM tbl_months GROUP BY id) AS m GROUP BY m.id
```

Unnfortunately I get

```
id  max_year    max_month
5   2020    1
6   2020    2
7   2020    3
8   2020    4
```

Any clues why? 
Is there another way to make it simpler and cleaner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`;

```
select t.*
from t
order by year desc, month desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks! Fast and clean. I will accept in a moment because you answered so fast that I can't do it now.

Answer (score 1):

with cte as
(
select * from temp where year = ( select max(year) from temp)
),cte2 as
(
select * from temp where month = ( select max(month) from temp)
)
select * from cte2

Answer (score 0):

As another option

```sql
select t1.* 
from t t1
where m = (select max(t2.m) from t t2 where y = (select max(t3.y) from t t3))
```

This way called subquery. I am not sure if this is faster vs `order by`/`limit` option, but might be depend on index.